# Need hover CSS to cover the full bar of the drop down menu option

Tags: drop-down-menu, navigation, hover

When I hover over the drop down menu items, only the parts around the text are highlighted, leaving unhighlighted space to the left of the menu item. What do I need to change to get this effect to cover the whole width of the drop down menu item?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Get Connected | Sage Spiritual</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sage.css">
    <style>
                @import  url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans&family=Newsreader:opsz@6..72&display=swap');
       
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header {
            font: 'Newsreader', Arial;
            background-image: url(images/sparklebanner.jpg);
            background-color: #7C8E93;
            color: #292330;
            font-size: 3.8rem;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

#logo {
    float: left;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Newsreader';
        }

/*navigation-------------------*/

#navigation {
            background-color: #EFE4DE;
            font-size: 1.8rem;
            border: 1px solid black;
}

        nav {
            background-color: #EFE4DE;
            font-family: "Newsreader", Arial;
            font-size: 1.8rem;
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 960px; 
            margin: 0 auto; 
        }

        nav a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

       #topnav {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #topnav li {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 1.8rem;
        }

        #topnav li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #topnav li ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #F7F2EF;
        }

        #topnav li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }

        #topnav li ul li {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #topnav li ul li ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            background-color: #F7F2EF;
        }

        #topnav li ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }

        #topnav li ul li ul li {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
  
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
    <header>
    <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/snake.png" width=120px height="175px" alt="sage spiritual snake logo" float="left"></a></div> 
        <h1><a href="index.html">Sage Spiritual</a></h1>  
    </header>
    <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
    <div id="navigation"><nav>
        <ul id="topnav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="magic.html">Magic</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="spells.html">Spells</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="witches.html">Witches</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="spellcasting.html">Spellcasting</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="energy.html">Energy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="altar.html">Altar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="tools.html">Significant Objects</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="candles.html">Candles</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="crystals.html">Crystals</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="pantry.html">Pantry</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="divination.html">Divination</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="timing.html">Timing &amp Cycles</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="holidays.html">Holidays</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="cosmic.html">Cosmic</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="mooncycles.html">Moon Cycles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="astro.html">Astrological Seasons</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
        </nav></div>
```

I've tried playing around with the padding and the display properites but nothings worked.